# Adding uniform UVs on multiple objects

Tags: uv

How can I apply uniform UV's on multiple objects/meshes (+100). It's fine with overlapping UV's

Example:

[image]

Comment: Hi :). Are you talking about uniform scale for the checker texture? You need to match the Texel Density. There are add-ons for that :))

Comment: Hi Jachym. I am very new to Blender. Really, I am just trying to apply UV's to multiple objects, instead of creating UV's for every object manually. If the UV's can be uniform (Not scaled in relation to object size) that would be great too :)

Comment: Hi :). You can simply select all vertices of all objects, and UV > Smart UV project. This will automatically unwrap all selected.

Comment: As I understand, you have to be in edit mode, to select vertices. When I select multiple objects, it's not possible for me to go to edit mode?

Comment: Hi :). Since Blender 2.8 you can enter Edit mode with multiple objects and unwrap them at once.